# How to send key bind occupied/interpreted by tmux to program running in tmux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, ranger

Let's say I'm running `ranger` *inside* `tmux` session, but I want to send a keyboard shortcut to `ranger` (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) which is already used in `tmux`.

Is there a passthrough mode to send key binding to underlying program similar to `vim`'s <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in "insert mode"?

I know you can set a key bind to send a key bind, but that's not practical to map all other program key bind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `send-keys`:

```
C-b : send C-h
```

`C-h` is not a key used by tmux by default (precisely so you don't need to do this).

If you are running 3.1 or master you could try something like this to make a key which sends the next key:

```
bind -n C-o command-prompt -kp key 'send %%%'
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, it's unpractical to map specific key since I need to send whatever shortcut below

Comment: I didn't suggest mapping specific keys, I gave you two examples that will work for any key. But if you are regularly wanting to use C-h or any other key in applications inside tmux, it is probably an unwise choice for a key for tmux itself.

Comment: Ahh.. I just got your edit... I'll try the 2nd one

Comment: The second one worked. Thanks.